# Minimum distance between two rotated rectangles with different angles

Tags: geometry

How can I calculate the minimum distance between two rectangles?
It is easy for rectangles which have no angles (i.e. `0` degrees one), but for *rotated* rectangles with any different angles I do not know how to do it.

Can you recommend any way?

WhiteFlare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check either they intersect first (try to take point from one rectangle and check either it is inside other rectangle).
   There are several ways to do it. One method (**not the best one**, but easy to explain) is the following.
    Let `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4` - rectangle points, `T` - some other point. 
   Then count squares for triangles:
    `S1 = (A1,A2,T)`, `S2 = S(A2,A3,T)`, `S3 = S(A3, A4, T)`, `S4 = S(A4, A1, A2)`. 
   Let `S_rectangle` be reactangle square. 
   Then `T` lies inside rectangle <=> `S1 + S2 + S3 + S4 = S_rectangle`.
   If reactangles don't intersect each other, then do these steps.
2. Calculate coordinates of all 8 points of 2 rectangles.
3. Take minimum among all 4 * 4 = 16 pairs of points (points from different rectangles).
    Let's denote it `min_1`.
4. Then, take some point from the first rectangle (4 ways to do it),
    take 4 segments of another rectangle (4 ways),
    check either perpendicular from that point to that segment gets inside segment.
    Take the mininmum of such perpendiculars. Let's denote it `min_2`.
5. The same as in `3`, but take point from the second rectangle, lines from the first:
    you get `min_3`.
6. `result = min(min_1, min_2, min_3)`

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft, then, the distance equals zero, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Calculate coordinates of all 8
   points of 2 rectangles.
2. Take the two lowest distances among
   all 4 * 4 = 16 pairs of points
   (points from different rectangles). 
   And get the 3 points P1, P2 and P3
   {Two of them belong to one rectangle
   and the third to the other}
3. The 2 Points belong to one rectangle
   should considered as segment, Now
   find the Short distance between a
   segment and the third point.

Comment: Because of (3), your method won't work for two parallel segments where one is longer than the other (and who share the same x-coord somewhere in the middle if they're parallel to the latter axis)